# Prove that a quadratically-constrained linear program (QCLP) is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, reductions, decision-problem, linear-programming

> Show that if we strengthen linear programming by also allowing constraints of the form $$ \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j = b,
> $$ for integers $b$ and $a_{ij}$, then the problem becomes NP-complete.

---

This is a practice problem that I am trying to solve. I really do not know how to approach, or reason about it. I understand that if $i =j$ for instance, then there would be non-linear polynomial constraints. So then, this will not be a linear program anymore. Particularly, $x^2 = b \implies$ two areas of solutions, so I suppose this affects the linear program somehow.

I have tried reducing SAT to this problem ,but with no success and it also seems like a wrong approach.Now I am thinking Vertex Cover, but I am not sure where to begin. Can anyone give some insights on this problem ?

Comment: Interesting... "strengthening" is the opposite of what I would've called it, since quadratic constraints are weaker than linear ones. I'm guessing they were going for "make more powerful".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a graph $G$ and a parameter $k$, consider the linear program with a variable $x_v$ for each vertex $v$, and the following constraints:

- $x_v \leq 1$ for all vertices $v$
- $\sum_v x_v \ge k$
- $x_u x_v = 0$ whenever $(u,v)$ is an edge

This program is feasible iff $G$ contains an independent set of size $k$.

Answer (score 4):

You can force a variable $x_i$ to be binary introducing a new variable $y_i$ and adding the quadratic constraint $y_i^2 = 1$ (forcing $y_i$ to be either $1$ or $-1$) and the linear constraint $2 x_i =  y_i + 1$. It turns out that this is the only type of quadratic constraint needed.

Given two binary variables $x_i$, $x_j$, you can force another binary variable $x_k$ to be equal to their logical "and" by writing the linear constraints $x_k \le x_i$, $x_k \le x_j$, $x_k \ge x_i + x_j -1$. Also, given a binary variable $x_k$ you can force another binary variable to $x_h$ to be equal to the logical "not" of $x_h$ by writing the linear constraint $x_h = 1-x_k$.
We have then ensured that $x_h = x_i \text{ NAND } x_j$. Since the NAND gate is a universal gate, you can take any instance of [circuit SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_satisfiability_problem), convert it into a circuit consisting only of NAND gates, and then convert it into a linear program with quadratic constraints by:

- Creating a binary variable for each circuit input.
- Writing the above set of constraints for each NAND gate in the circuit.
- Setting the objective function to $\max x^*$, where $x^*$ is the variable corresponding to the circuit's output.

Then, deciding whether the circuit SAT instance is a "yes" instance corresponds to checking whether the objective function of an optimal solution of the linear program is $1$.

Notice that both the transformation into a circuit having only NAND gates, and the above reduction can be performed in linear time.